# picking random name from text file in c# windows forms non repeatable

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

I was wondering how get on with this code, currently working on a tournament bracket system.

Currently I have created a comboBox that fetches all the lines from "log.txt" there are 16 lines in the txt file; then I created a assign button that is supposed to assign all the names into 16 textboxes called User1 --> User16, however the same name cant be repeated.

I looked at "**Array of list**" & "**Array of string**", but I seem to be stuck since I cant really figure out what to put in the code.

my random button looks like this at the moment:

```
private void assign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        x = rnd.Next(0, 16);
        User1.Text = comboBox2.Items[x].ToString();
        x = rnd.Next(0, 16);
        User2.Text = comboBox2.Items[x].ToString();
        x = rnd.Next(0, 16);
        User3.Text = comboBox2.Items[x].ToString();
        x = rnd.Next(0, 16);
        User4.Text = comboBox2.Items[x].ToString();
        and so on untill i hit 
        x = rnd.Next(0, 16);
        User16.Text = comboBox2.Items[x].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest, but not necessarily most efficient, way to do this is to put all your strings into a `List<string>` and remove them randomly one-by-one. This would work a lot better if you put all your textboxes into a collection as well. For example, given a list of strings called `myStrings` and a collection of textboxes called `myTextboxes`, you could:

```
for (var i=0; i < myStrings.Count; i++) 
{
    var idx = rnd.Next(0, myStrings.Count);
    myTextboxes[i].Text = myStrings[idx];    // Note: we are assuming the two collections have 
                                             // the same length
    myStrings.RemoveAt(idx);        
}
```

This is very easy to implement and very easy to get right, but it's not terribly efficient (for 16 items, it probably doesn't matter) because your collection is repeatedly resized. For a more efficient approach, first shuffle your strings using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and then just assign the first entry from your shuffled strings to the first textbox, the second to the second, and so on.

Comment: If OP can use Linq, getting the strings in random order is as easy as `var rnd = new Random(); var randomStrings = lst.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next());` -- just be carefull not to call it in a very tight loop, as the seed for `Random()` is time based and would result in the same "random" sequence. And you also might want to add `.ToList()` after `OrderBy(...)`, if you want to access items by index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a List, and after each assignment you could remove the assigned item from the list. This would prevent duplicates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about removing each item after selecting it?

Try something like

```
 comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(x);
```

After adding it and each time your

```
x = rnd.Next(0, 16);
```

code will reduce to

```
x = rnd.Next(0, 15);
```

until it reaches zero.
A different approach would be after selecting one randomly loop through all the filled ones (or all in general for simpler code) and check if it is already selected. If already selected get a new one until it's different.

For that you could use an array of textboxes (store what you have in an array) and loop through them like so

```
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    if(textBoxArray[i].Text==comboBox2.Items[x].toString()){
    chosen=true;
}
```

But removing them from the combobox is much simpler and much faster as code. If you want them to still appear in your combobox you could simultaneously in a List, get your items from that List and remove it from there. 
The user will not see anything.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, is fairly simple.

First, you know there are 16 items in total. You don't need to randomize the list but rather, randomize the index that you use to access the item of the list. This part you know.

In order to avoid repeating items, you need to keep a list of indexes that have already been used. Once you have determined an unused index, that's when you need to access your list.

Example:

```
class Sample
{
   List<int> _usedIndexes;

   public Sample()
   {
      _usedIndexes = new List<int>();
   }   

   public int GetRandomIndex(int s, e)
   {
      Random rnd = new Random();

      //Initialize with a random number
      int x = rnd.Next(s, e);

      //While the index exists in the list of used indexes, get another random number.
      while(_usedIndexes.Exists(index => index == x))
      {
         x = rnd.Next(s, e);
      }

      //Add the number to the list of used indexes 
      _usedIndexes.Add(x);

      return x;
   }
}
```

Then you simply access the List of names you have with the index you have acquired as follows:

```
int unusedIndex = GetRandomIndex(0, 16);

User1.Text = comboBox2.Items[unusedIndex].ToString();
```